# unable set variable for external javascript file

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have two files(html and js) as shown below.

test.html

```
  <body>
  <script>
    /*Loads the fb api*/
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '<APP-ID>',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
     TimelineScript(); /* function that loads the external javascript */
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));

  . . .
  . . .
  . . .

  function TimelineScript(){
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
         var dt = new Date();
         var _testvar = 100;/*Used in the external javascript file*/       

         /*Loading my external javscript*/
         (function() {
            var sa = document.createElement('script'); 
            sa.type = 'text/javascript'; 
            sa.async = true;
            sa.src = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/javascripts/testing.js?random='+dt.getTime();
            var script_tag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            script_tag.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, script_tag);

          })();

     } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
       alert("the user is logged in to Facebook, but not auth your app");
     } else {
       alert('user is not logged into fb!');
     }
  });
 }

 </script>

  . . .
  . . .
  . . .

  </body>
```

testing.js

```
alert('loaded testing .js'); //works
alert(_testvar); //throws error
```

The alert in testing.js file throws up an error `_testvar is not defined` in the firebug console. The alert works fine if I have a plain script(without all the facebook api code) that just declares a variable and then loads the external js. What is going wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript creates a new variable scope for each function you create, whether it is anonymous or not.

So the `_testvar` in the following code is local to the anonymous function, and inaccessible by anything else, least of all another script file:

```
  function TimelineScript(){
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
         var dt = new Date();
         var _testvar = 100;/*Used in the external javascript file*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define "_testvar" outside of the function it should work. This allows the variable to be used across scopes outside of just the one function:

```
<script>
var _testvar = 0;
....
function TimelineScript(){
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
       var dt = new Date();
       _testvar = 100;/*Used in the external javascript file*/       

       /*Loading my external javscript*/
       (function() {
          var sa = document.createElement('script'); 
          sa.type = 'text/javascript'; 
          sa.async = true;
          sa.src = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/javascripts/testing.js?random='+dt.getTime();
          var script_tag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
          script_tag.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, script_tag);

        })();

   } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
     alert("the user is logged in to Facebook, but not auth your app");
   } else {
     alert('user is not logged into fb!');
   }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The variable **_testvar** is defined through **FB.getLoginStatus** asynchronus (i think) call.
So, the time you're testing the variable (that is, right away) this isnt even set yet because of FB trying to get login status.

This is because of **asynchronous** mode; you might try to set synchronous mode or checking **_testvar** when you get your async response, not right after the code.